# SteamAuth PHP Login System

Tags: php, authentication, steam

Anyone knows how can I allow only some SteamIDS to login in the SteamAuth system made by SmItH197 (https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication)?

Comment: You could have a list of ids which you check against the result of https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication/blob/master/steamauth/steamauth.php#L34

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm not understanding...

Answer (score 0):

You could have a list of ids which you check against the login.

So create an array of allowed ids in `SteamAuthentication/steamauth/SteamConfig.php`

```
<?php
//Version 3.2
$steamauth['apikey'] = ""; // Your Steam WebAPI-Key found at http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey
$steamauth['domainname'] = ""; // The main URL of your website displayed in the login page
$steamauth['logoutpage'] = ""; // Page to redirect to after a successfull logout (from the directory the SteamAuth-folder is located in) - NO slash at the beginning!
$steamauth['loginpage'] = ""; // Page to redirect to after a successfull login (from the directory the SteamAuth-folder is located in) - NO slash at the beginning!

// System stuff
if (empty($steamauth['apikey'])) {die("<div style='display: block; width: 100%; background-color: red; text-align: center;'>SteamAuth:<br>Please supply an API-Key!<br>Find this in steamauth/SteamConfig.php, Find the '<b>\$steamauth['apikey']</b>' Array. </div>");}
if (empty($steamauth['domainname'])) {$steamauth['domainname'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];}
if (empty($steamauth['logoutpage'])) {$steamauth['logoutpage'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];}
if (empty($steamauth['loginpage'])) {$steamauth['loginpage'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];}

// allow only these ids
$allowed_ids = [
    '123abc',
    '987zxy',
];
?>
```

Then in the file which does the auth `SteamAuthentication/steamauth/steamauth.php` [line 34](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication/blob/master/steamauth/steamauth.php#L34) check the ids against the one matched. If its not in the array do a redirect to an error page which tells the user, they are not allowed to login.

```
...
  preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

  if (!in_array($matches[1], $allowed_ids)) {
      exit(header('Location: some-page-with-error.php'));
  }

  $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];
...
```